# PyQt on Python3.5: ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to use PyQt5 on python3.5 (linux) but for the life of me cannot get the modules to import:

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr 10 2016, 14:34:46) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
>>>
```

But importing PyQt5 works...

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>>
```

I've searched all over Internet but cannot seem to find a way past this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Importing a package does not load subpackages. So the fact that `import PyQt5` works implies nothing about `PyQt5.QtCore`. Searching for the error message you get I see some results saying there is a problem with a wheel with python3.5. If you try to use python3.6 does this work? In fact [`PySlice_AdjustIndices`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_AdjustIndices) API call is documented as new in python3.6...

Comment: Thanks for that, Python3.6 does work! It seems that there was some confusion in the package I was installing that required PyQt. Python3.6.5 works properly!